# Google PubSub : Explicit NACK with pull?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there a way to explicitly nack a message with PULL subscriber and not to wait until the timeout deadline?

My impression is that such functionality does not exist and the only supported model with PULL subscriber is the implicit nack - a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call ModifyAckDeadline and set the new deadline to zero.

Comment: I am not sure I understand completely. Could you please provide a code sample? Let's say I have ack IDs of three messages in flight. How could I fail the second message immediately, while acknowledging the other two?

Comment: ModifyAckDeadline can be called with a scope of a single message.